# How to execute a cmd on a bunch of files, where the parameters needed are <filename.ext> and <filename>

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a tool that wants a filename.ext to make a bunch of files, and also wants a directory name to put them in. In my case filename/ would do.

Directory:
Filename1.ext
Filename2.ext

cmd Filename1.ext Filename
cmd Filename2.ext Filename2

I've been trying to tackle it via find, but maybe there is a better way?
`find . -iname "*.ext" -exec cmd ... ?`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, not sure if it is optimal.
`find -iname "*.ext" -exec bash -c 'cmd "$1" "${1%.*}"' bash {} \;`

This will call `cmd filename.ext filename` for each matching file

Updated solution with input from ilkkachu, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to recurse down into subdirectories? (this was not explicitly mentioned in the question)  Since you're using `-iname` rather than `-name`, does that mean that you expect there to be files with suffixes `.Ext`, `ExT`, `.EXT`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what's the extention of the <filename.ext>, try

```
for i in *.ext; do cmd "$i" "$(basename -s .ext "$i")"; done
```